# Clip the norm of the gradient in libtorch-C++

Tags: libtorch

Is there any API to clip the gradients of a network? Or, I need to develop myself?

Best,
Afshin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one:
`Tensorat::clamp(const Tensor &self, c10::optional<Scalar> min = c10::nullopt, c10::optional<Scalar> max = c10::nullopt)`, though I also implemented myself.